# SQL query to select online users minutos ago using date ()

Tags: php, sql

Hi i have found a tutorial to learn how to manage a Register Login, form he is using Mysql, but i already made changes for mysqli and in the future i will change to PDO. but i want to learn other stuff also for example

http://gigaspartan.com/2010/11/26/how-to-build-a-full-featured-login-system/

in the tutorial everytime you login you update the online table.. like this.

```
$time = date('U')+50;
mysql_query("UPDATE `admins` SET `online` = '".$time."' WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'");
```

And in the page where i want to display the actual users logged in i have this but im showing all users .. i meant once you logged even if a week has pased you seem to be still online XD ja.

```
 <?php

   //select all rows where there online time is more than the current time
   $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `admins` WHERE `online` > '".date('i')."'")or die(mysql_error()); ;

   if (mysql_num_rows($res)==0) { echo "0";}
   else {
   //loop for each row
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
   //echo  each username found to be online with a dash to split them
    echo $row['username'].", ";
                            } 
                        }

                            ?>
```

Also related to understand this..

I have created another table for blog articles wich uses de same date() function to set a "publish date" and "unpublish date"   the idea is to set the starting date and end date for an article to appear on the blog..

My idea is to build it using a query to check if today date() is between that prestablish range of dates in my database, but i think i have to understand better first for example why my users seems to bee online always . XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem (all users are listed, even the offline ones) occurs because you use `date('i')` where it should be `date('U')` in the `online > date` part of your SQL query.

The parameters or `date()` are available and explained [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: Ok but know even ig im logged in, it display 0 users logged in.. wich is incorrect actually. and also ¿where is doing the current time or date check? i do not understand that, i think that missing, but im not sure..

Comment: Could you paste the currently used SQL query? Also you may wish to try to directly test your query in e.g. your PHPMyAdmin by using `SELECT * FROM admins WHERE online > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` and see whether that returns the rows you actually want.